# HTML embed rtmp video to page

Tags: html, stream, rtsp, rtmp, wowza

If it is possible how can I embed a video which is played with this link to my webpage?

```
rtmp://192.168.178.22:1235/live
```

or this

```
rtsp://192.168.178.58:1935/test/myStream
```

That link is created using Wowza Streaming Engine.

In the Wowza panel it gets shown properly.

If I call the link in my browser I get nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the RTMP stream using a Flash based player like Strobe, JwPlayer, Flowplayer.

You can start from this [Strobe setup tutorial provided by Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-strobe-media-playback-with-a-wowza-media-server).